# Get the result of normal distribution via. machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution

I have data of survey result of each questions, and like to find the formula\pattern to calculate\predict the customer satisfactions index. we assume the satisfactions index are normal distribution, and the formula is:
Satisfaction Index = ∑ Weight(i) * Rate(i) , Rate(i) is the rating score of the question i, the goal is to figure out Weight(i)

Any idea to figure out Weight(i) based on the normal distributed Satisfaction Index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use linear regression. Regress the index as a function of the rating score of each question. If you assume that the index and ratings are normally distributed, and that the index is a linear combination of the rates, then this is the correct thing to do.

However this probably isn't true. There are probably nonlinearities in the satisfaction index. In this case, you could use a neural network or an SVM to try to make a better predictor. But you should first try the linear regression and see if it gives a good fit.